# How can I Reset Bitmap Pixels in SKBitmap SKiaSharp

Tags: c#, xamarin, skiasharp

I am trying to clear a bitmap in SkiaSharp in Xamarin, the bitmap is drawn by a SkCanvas,

```
    new SKCanvas(SkBitmap bitmap)
```

but at times i need to clear the bitmap data.

```
    SkCanvas.Clear()
```

tries to fill the bitmap with SKColor(0,0,0,0) pixels, but premul with the existing pixels it doesn't affect it.

```
    SKBitmap.Reset()
```

doesnt work because it resets the object completely including the size.
Any idea how can i achieve this in an efficient way, not by going through all the pixels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to clear the pixel data, you WILL have to clear each pixel. There is no way around this.

To clear the bitmap/canvas, you should use `SKCanvas.Clear()`, but remember, you can pass in a color. So if you want the pixel data to be all zeroes, you can just `SKCanvas.Clear(0)`.

I think this is what you are asking, if not I may need more info.

**EDIT**

Another thing that just occurred is that there is a `SKBitmap.Erase(SKColor)`. This may be better as there is no need for a canvas.